Denodo equivalent of collect_set, named_struct in Hive
I have a query which is in Hive as follows
Select
acc,
collect_set(named_struct ( 'acc', acc,
'name', name,
'age', age))
group by acc
But this is not working in Denodo VQL. What is the corresponding functions for these that will work in Denodo VQL

What does "is not working" means? Are you receiving an error? Are you receiving unexpected output? Please clarify.

Receiving error. Can’t project columns

Please add the full error as text inside the question

To achieve something similar in Denodo, you can try using GROUP_CONCAT to concatenate the fields in JSON format. Here's an example for your case:
SELECT
acc,
GROUP_CONCAT(false, ', ', '', acc, name, CAST(age AS STRING)) AS details
FROM your_table
GROUP BY acc
I think that this will allow you to group the data and simulate a structured format using strings. Hope this helps!
